# How to run stats in HAProxy 1.6.4 on same port as frontend?

Tags: port, config, haproxy

I'm using HAProxy 1.6.4 and want to enable the stats. (/haproxy?stats)

Here is my cfg:

```
global
   log 127.0.0.1 local2
   daemon
   maxconn 256

defaults
   log global
   timeout connect  5000
   timeout client  10000
   timeout server  10000

frontend http-in
   bind *:8080
   default_backend testb

backend testb
   balance roundrobin
   server s1 123.456.789.0:443 maxconn 32
   server s2 123.456.789.1:443 maxconn 32

listen statistics
   bind *:8080
   mode http
   stats enable
```

If I run statistics on other port than 8080 it works, but how can I run it on the same port as my frontend (8080), which is running in the default `mode tcp`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it by redirecting to your self and using access list like this:

```
global
   log 127.0.0.1 local2
   daemon
   maxconn 256

defaults
   log global
   timeout connect  5000
   timeout client  10000
   timeout server  10000

listen stats :1936
   mode http
   stats enable
   stats hide-version
   stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
   stats uri /
   stats auth myUser:myPassword

frontend http-in
   bind *:8080
   acl is_www hdr_end(host) -i www.mysite.com
   acl is_stat hdr_end(host) -i stat.mysite.com  

   use_backend srv_www if is_www
   use_backend srv_stat if is_stat

backend srv_www
   balance roundrobin
   server s1 123.456.789.0:443 maxconn 32
   server s2 123.456.789.1:443 maxconn 32

backend srv_stat
   server Local 127.0.0.1:1936
```

When going to your server with `www`, it takes you to the web server.
But using `stat`, it redirects you from your input port `8080` to `1936` whee stat is running

Comment: I don't think this is appropriate syntax for haproxy 1.6.

'listen' cannot handle unexpected argument ':1936'

Comment: command ```haproxy -c -f haproxy.cfg``` using above file in haproxy 1.7 results: ```[ALERT] 095/154845 (1343) : Error(s) found in configuration file : haproxy.cfg```

Comment: @JoelHandwell in the new HAProxy version 1.6.5 the syntax has changed https://superuser.com/questions/1080306/haproxy-configuration-errors

Answer (score 0):

This is just an educated guess. You can't serve the `stats` page in `tcp` mode because it's proxying at layer4. In this mode, haproxy only knows IPs and ports from incoming packets and routes it accordingly based on defined rules.

Unlike `http` mode (layer7), it has more info to work on like HTTP headers where `path` is available and use it to know when to serve the `/haproxy?stats` page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use a your path, it really easy.
this should work

```
global
   log 127.0.0.1 local2
   daemon
   maxconn 256

defaults
   log global
   timeout connect  5000
   timeout client  10000
   timeout server  10000

frontend http-in
   bind *:8080

   stats enable
   stats uri /stats

   default_backend testb

backend testb
   balance roundrobin
   server s1 123.456.789.0:443 maxconn 32
   server s2 123.456.789.1:443 maxconn 32
```

you can then access the haproxy stats from
http://< hostname >:8080/stats

*(tested on haproxy 2.5.5)*