# HAPROXY: Ports not routing and stats not showing

Tags: docker, gitlab, devops, haproxy

**Question**
 What errors do you see in my config.

**Background** Learning HAProxy Config, I want to get the basic config setup before I use the runtime API to do this. I'm running in a docker-container.

```
76fd2cab1583        gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest   "/assets/wrapper"        5 days ago          Up 5 days (healthy)   0.0.0.0:3222->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3001->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3443->443/tcp   gitlab
de7fe0513233        registry                  "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   5 days ago          Up 5 days             0.0.0.0:3002->5000/tcp
```

**Problem** : Stats don't show on 8080. gitlab doesn't show on 22.

**SUCCESS** : gitlab does show on 80 at 127.0.0.1:80/devops/gitlab

```
global
    daemon
    maxconn 256

defaults
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend fe_main
  bind *:80
  mode http


  acl gitlab_url_80 url_beg -i /devops/gitlab
  use_backend be_gitlab_80 if gitlab_url_80
  acl gitlab_url_22 url_beg -i /devops/gitlab
  use_backend be_gitlab_22 if gitlab_url_22
  acl gitlab_url_443 url_beg -i /devops/gitlab
  use_backend be_gitlab_443 if gitlab_url_443
  acl docker_url url_beg -i /devops/docker
  use_backend be_docker if docker_url

backend be_gitlab_80
  mode http
  server gitlab 127.0.0.1:3001
backend be_gitlab_22
  mode http
  server gitlab 127.0.0.1:3222
backend be_gitlab_443
  mode http
  server gitlab 127.0.0.1:3443
backend be_docker
  mode http
  server docker 127.0.0.1:3002



frontend privoxy-front
 bind :8080
 mode http
 default_backend public_www

  # public access (limited to this backend only)
backend public_www
    mode http
    server srv1 127.0.0.1:8080
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats scope   .
    stats uri     /admin?stats
    stats realm   Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats auth    admin1:AdMiN123
    stats auth    admin2:AdMiN321

# internal monitoring access (unlimited)
backend private_monitoring
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri     /admin?stats
    stats refresh 5s
```

Comment: For your TLS/SSL connections, as well as your SSH connection, you are going to need `mode tcp` as opposed to `mode http`. Unless you run a TLS frontend on haproxy as well.

Comment: @TravisHegner, so I'll change my be_gitlab_22 to tcp. Any ideas on my stats front_end/back_end?

Comment: I've always run stats in a separate `listen` directive, so on it's own port. If you are intent on running it on the same front end, then this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36912330/2639647

Comment: I see the listen directive in the link. I used that without the additional backend. Didn't work.

--listen stats
   mode http
   bind *:8080
   stats enable
   stats hide-version
   stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
   stats uri /
   stats auth myUser:myPassword

Comment: @TravisHegner, so the listen for stats doesn't work and I tried.. tcp on the backends of 22 and 433 and I get this error `http frontend 'fe_main' (/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:10) tries to use incompatible tcp backend 'be_gitlab_22'`